# Facebook iframe app login & install page cause double facebook frame

Tags: facebook

the iframe app that I have cause double facebook header to show when user is prompted to login or install.

This code basically caused it.
FB.Facebook.requireLogin(function(exception){ 
});

How can I prevent that? I saw blog post about using javascript to do the redirect, but how can I do that?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

use target="_parent" for any links that you have in your iframe application. that will definitely solve your problem.